# Can I change onscreen HTML when a JSON/AJAX response is successful?

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Summary:** 
I have a listing of helpdesk type requests.
When a document is uploaded to an incident on the list by clicking a folder icon, the icon changes to reflect the upload.
I would like a Status (M or D) on that same row to change at that same time.

---

**In other words:**
Using Json an ajax call is made and a class of a specific .tr element(.td) is changed with the response. 
That all works great.

I'm placing my logic just after the change because in that same .tr I need a different element(.td) to change also.

I need the html in a .td to 'flip'. In other words, if the data in the element is an "M" I want it to change to a "D" and if it's a "D" I want it to change to an "M".

I CANNOT get just ONE Row to change - They ALL Change.

This is VERY abbreviated. 
HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="StatusID"><span title="MFTA ACTIVE" class="status"><font color="RED">M</font></span></td>
    <td class="tar">  003430</td>
    <td class="comments"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm showing ONLY the new JQuery...

```
      // Flip the status if this is an open TAR
 var dspStatus =$('.tar:contains(' + tarNo + ')').parents('tr').find('.status').text();
  if (dspStatus == "M") {
    dspStatus = "D";
  }
  else if (dspStatus == "D") {
    dspStatus = "M";
  }
 $('.tar:contains(' + tarNo + ')').parents('tr').find('.Status').html(dspStatus);
```

Of course the fiddle wont run but it helped me with a couple other things :https://jsfiddle.net/qbw30oLz/8/
(To see move of the Java script: https://jsfiddle.net/SJSooze/7z0xs0v1/3/)

Comment: Use `$('#StatusID').text();`

Comment: Why the DOWN VOTE?

Comment: I'd really like to know - I worked on this Friday AND for 5hrs today before I asked for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this out !!   You can directly use the class status and if you do not use an else condition, if your dspStatus is M then eventually it becomes D and then again it would be changed to M as it is D. So better use else if or else.

```
  var dspStatus = $('.status').text();
  if (dspStatus == "M") {
    dspStatus = "D";
  }
  else if (dspStatus == "D") {
    dspStatus = "M";
  }
  $('.status').text(dspStatus );
```

Comment: PAT, I think you are VERY close!!!  I got a change BUT LOL!!!!  Status changed to MMMMMMMMMMMMMMDDDMMMMMMMCMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMCMMCCCCCCC      I think that is EVERY Status on the page!  LOLOL

Comment: try this - change this in the first line
`var dspStatus = $('.tar:contains("003430")').parents('tr').find('.status').text();`
and this in the last line 
`$('.tar:contains("003430")').parents('tr').find('.status').text(dspStatus );`

Comment: OK, now I get only ONE "D" but Every row changes!

var dspStatus =$('.tar:contains(' + tarNo + ')').parents('tr').find('.status').text();
  if (dspStatus == "M") {
    dspStatus = "D";
  }
  else if (dspStatus == "D") {
    dspStatus = "M";
  }
  $('.status').text(dspStatus );
 $('.tar:contains(' + tarNo + ')').parents('tr').find('.Status').html(dspStatus);